# JQuery - How do I determine if checkbox is checked in selector?

Tags: jquery

I need to know if certain checkboxes are checked or not checked in order to trigger other page changes.  This is what I am trying to do below, but it doesn't seem to be bringing back my checkbox.

```
$("input[name*='slRecordToProcess'][value='L']")
```

Here is what is rendered:

```
<input name="j_id0:j_id3:slRecordsToProcess" id="j_id0:j_id3:slRecordsToProcess:1" value="L" type="checkbox" checked="checked" onchange="javascript:EstimateCost(this)">
```

Comment: `if ($("input[name*='slRecordToProcess'][value='L']").is(':checked')) alert("It is checked!");`  Just write a correct selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) in your selector to select only checked elements:

```
$("input[name*='slRecordsToProcess']:checked")
```

Comment: It works when I spell things correctly!!!  UGH!    $("input[name*='slRecordsToProcess'][value='L']").is(':checked')

Answer (score 0):

Try this

You will get all checked checkbox

```
$("input:checkbox[name=type]:checked").each(function()
{

});
```

Another Example : http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all checked checkboxes on the page, the correct way to do it is with the [`:checkbox`](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) and [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) psudoclasses:

```
var $allCheckedBoxes = $('input:checkbox:checked');
```

If you have a particular checkbox and want to see if it is checked, you should use [one of the three following methods](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

```
if (elem.checked) {}
if ($(elem).prop("checked")) {}
if ($(elem).is(":checked")) {}
```